# when styling a div for the second time it doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set the opacity of a div to 0 at first then set it back to 1 again when a for loop finishes , but it stays hidden .. the weird thing is that when a i I fire an alert for the opacity of the div it gives me 1.

```
document.addEventListener("click",function(event){
  const isButton = event.target.id === 'ui-id-2';
  const isSpan1 = event.target.innerHTML === '&lt;&lt;';
  const isSpan2 = event.target.innerHTML === '&gt;&gt;';

  if (isButton || isSpan2 || isSpan1) {
  document.querySelector('#base').style.opacity="0";
  }
  });


 browser.storage.local.get({obj:""},function(result){   

 var username=result["obj"][0].name.split(" ")[0];

if(result["obj"].length>0){

       document.querySelector("#ui-id-2").onclick=function(){
updateurl(username);
}

   if(document.querySelector("li").getAttribute("aria-selected") != "false")
{     
updateurl(username);
}


       if(document.querySelectorAll("li")[1].getAttribute("aria-selected") != "false")
{               


var win;
var percentinput;
var thisInput;
var percent;
var thisOutput;
var newoutput;

for(var i=18;i<=139;i=i+11){
 win=document.querySelectorAll("td")[i].textContent;
for(var j=0;j<result["obj"].length;j++){
    if(parseFloat(win).toFixed()==result["obj"][j].input){
        thisInput=result["obj"][j].input;
        thisOutput=result["obj"][j].output;
         percentinput=(parseFloat(thisInput)/100);
              percent=percentinput*parseFloat(thisOutput);
              newoutput=parseFloat(thisInput)-percent;
        newoutput=Math.ceil(newoutput / 5) * 5;
        newoutput=newoutput.toFixed(2);
     document.querySelectorAll("td")[i].textContent=newoutput;
    }
}
```

//this is the line that i want it to work

```
 if(i==139)       document.querySelector('#base').style.opacity="1";
 }

 }

 }

 });
```

Comment: Please always add ALL the ***relevant*** code (HTML, CSS) into a code snippet so we can reproduce your issue and provide a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but better solution that should work is like
if you create class

```
.hidden {
  display : none;    
}
```

and just toggle/add/remove this class from/to your element

Comment: I will try it !